# Can ZF-Reg. be subsumed in ZF?

Tags: set-theory

Assuming that $\sf ZF$ is consistent, is it the case that for every consistent recursively enumerable theory $\sf T $ that extends the theory $\sf ZF-Reg. +\neg Reg.$ in the language of set theory, there is a model $(M, \in)$ of $\sf ZF$ and a set $ M^- \subseteq M $ such that $(M^-,\in^{M^-})$ is a model of $\sf T$?

Comment: Do you require T to be r.e.? And also the requirement that ZF and T are consistent, i.e. have set models is also an assumption you have, right?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri, Yes! I've added all those requirements? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Set $T = \mathsf{ZF} - \mathsf{Reg} + \neg\mathsf{Reg} + \exists x(x\in x)$. This is well known to be equiconsistent with ZF. On the other hand, obviously no restriction of a model of ZF can satisfy $\exists x(x\in x)$.

Comment: I'm confused about this answer. It is not forced on us to take $\in^{M^-}$ as the true $\in$, right? Or maybe the OP intended this? Because if not, this is possible to do.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri: I'm assuming that $\in^{M^-}$ is supposed to be the restriction of $\in^M$ to $M^-$. Otherwise the answer would be "obviously yes", simply because a consistent $T$ must have have a countable model and $M$ is necessary infinite.

Comment: I think there is bit more nuance to it, as we are not assuming choice as far as I see and Lowenheim Skolem needs some choice to get that by the argument you propose (you at the least need DC to do that if my memory serves me right), and that's if by "being consistent" you mean having a model, otherwise you will also need the Henkin construction(which requires more choice in V). But assuming that $\in^{M^-}$ to be the restriction of the true $\in$, makes it obvious I guess.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri, yes my intention was the restriction Troposphere alluded to, I just didn't see the obvious.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri: If I remember correctly, all the choice you need for the Henkin construction in ZF comes for free if you can assume you have a well-ordering of the _vocabulary_ of the theory. In this case the language is fixed as the language of set theory, which is trivially well-orderable.